# Swift / iAd bannerView / how to set the position

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add iAd into my app using the following code:

```
var bannerView: ADBannerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bannerView.delegate = self
bannerView.hidden = true
bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 400, view.frame.size.width, bannerView.frame.size.height)
view.addSubview(bannerView)
```

Even using the `frame = CGRectMake` stuff, my banner is at the bottom of my app... No matter how I change the x/y values. The banner stays at the bottom... What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Exactly Where you want? and also change Y position and Run code.

Comment: i would want it in the middle of the screen (Y axis)

Comment: bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.frame.size.height/2, view.frame.size.width, 30)

Comment: Last time I checked, iAd will soon no longer be available.

Comment: @sanjihan source? what will be available instead?

Comment: nothing I guess. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Comment: oha! well thank you for saving me time! guess i have to use another ad-supplier then? google? thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as Follow:

```
var adBannerView: ADBannerView  
adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, screenBounds.width))
adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: screenBounds.width/2, y: screenBounds.height-adBannerView.frame.height)
adBannerView.delegate = self
adBannerView.hidden = true
view.addSubview(adBannerView)
```

Comment: Did u add bannerview in storyboard or Add programatically?

Comment: well yeah. this is working. any idea what caused the problem in my version?

Comment: you had not add adBannerView.center

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :-

```
var bannerView: ADBannerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bannerView =ADBannerView(adType:.Banner)
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = true
    bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height-bannerView.frame.size.height,view.frame.size.width,bannerView.frame.size.height)
    view.addSubview(bannerView)     
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the exactly output

Comment: sorry that i didnt gave you an upvote back then. just caught up. thanks for your effort